# Databricks throwing error: truncating data

Tags: sql, hadoop, databricks, azure-synapse, truncated

Whenever I try to save a specific DataFrame on the DW I get the message:

> ERROR:  An error occurred while calling o692.save.
>       : com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWSideException: SQL DW failed to execute the JDBC query produced by the connector.
>       Underlying SQLException(s):
>         - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered
>   filling record reader buffer: HadoopSqlException: String or binary
>   data would be truncated. [ErrorCode = 107090] [SQLState = S0001]

I've checked the size of the strings in my csv file. The bigger one has 38 chars.

This is my save/write method (worked for other DataFrames):

```
df.write\
 .format('com.databricks.spark.sqldw') \
 .option('url', conn_string_dw) \
 .option('maxStrLength', '4000') \
 .option('forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials', 'true') \
 .option('dbTable', db_table_name) \
 .option('tempDir', dw_temporary_path_url) \
 .option('truncate', 'False')\
 .mode('append')\
 .save()
```

What could be happening here?

Comment: What is your target table specification, please? My first check would be that the data file matches the column data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the final file. One specific cell contained multiple lines which caused this truncating problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same error using Databricks to send tables to Synapse. Suspected that one or more of my string cols in my spark Df had exceeded the 256 NVARCHAR default length.

1. Ran this on my databricks df to get the max length for every string column.

> 

```
import pandas as pd
df = df.toPandas()
dict([(v, df[v].apply(lambda r: len(str(r)) if r!=None else 0).max())for v in df.columns.values])
```

2. Found my culprit. Had a col with a max len of 416.
3. Changed my df.write procedure for Synapse to include maxStrLength as you have shown